# How to pass FormData and other variables too with one HTTP Post message? (Angular, Node)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I would like to send two kinds of data to the back end:

- a file in a FormData
- and a Book object

How can I send these two things with one single post?
The image upload is already working!

Thank you for advance!

---

Front end: Angular

```
upload(image: any, book: Book) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image, image.name);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/books/upload', formData);
  }
```

Back end: Express.js

```
router.post('/upload', checkAuth, multer({storage: storage}).single("image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file.filename);
  console.log(req.body.book);
  res.status(200);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save FormData with File Upload in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468957/save-formdata-with-file-upload-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 0):

you can also append your object in formdata

```
   formData.append('book',JSON.stringify(book));
```